# How to pass jS variable for API integration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

As part of a membership solution I am building, I am using jS and JSON to manage membership data, I have the following code which does as it should:

```
$(document).on('click', '#triggerLink', function() {

    MemberStack.onReady.then(async function(member) {

        var metadata = await member.getMetaData() <--- returns all metadata as JSON
        var email = member["email"]; <--- pull user email into `email` jS variable

        /*Do other unrelated stuff here which is working.*/
        window.location.href = "https://URL.com/test";

    })

});
```

Now that I have the users email address stored in a variable called `email`, I need to connect this to Mailchimp via one of their approved [methods](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/automation-email/start-automated-email/). The problem is I don't see an option that I could call in this scenario, I was hoping for a `$.ajax` type method but there isn't one.

Is it possible to pass the jS variable `email` into one of [these](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/automation-email/start-automated-email/) options using my current code?

Answer (score -1):

What i understood is, i just need to call fetch method and send email id.
eg.

```
$(document).on('click', '#triggerLink', function() {

    MemberStack.onReady.then(async function(member) {

        var metadata = await member.getMetaData() <--- returns all metadata as JSON
        var email = member["email"]; <--- pull user email into `email` jS variable

fetch(`https://server.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/{workflow_id}/emails/${email}}`)
  .then(response => response.json());
  
        /*Do other unrelated stuff here which is working.*/
        window.location.href = "https://URL.com/test";

    })

});
```